# FullCalendar - Half day in dayGridMonth

Tags: javascript, css, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a calendar with FullCalendar that allows me to post my absences.
For some absences, they are only half a day (morning or afternoon), and for others, they can last several days but end at 12:00.

The goal is therefore in the monthly view to display the events without filling a whole cell when it is not necessary:

[image: calendar]

So I have my list of events that contain extendedProps, letting me know if I have to correct their width to take into account the half-days.

For these, I manage to modify their width, thanks to this function:

```
eventRender: function (info) {
    // HALF DAY
    var half = info.event.extendedProps.halfDay;

    if (half == true) {
    // console.log(info);

    var elementStyle = info.el;
    jQuery(elementStyle).css('width', 50 + "px");

    }
```

And I have :

[image]

So that's good, but I need to improve the function to take into account the total size of the width and perform a calculation that will reduce it. Because here I assign it the value '50' in width.

For example :

An event that lasts 2.5 days: a calculation that determines the width to occupy on the calendar in the monthly view so that it does not take the place of 3 days but 2.5 days. Taking into account of course the size of the screen.

And for an event that lasts only half a day, make sure that it only fills half of a box as in the image, but with a better calculation.

The problem is that I do not find a way to do that. I tell myself that I should already get the width of a cell according to the size of the screen and that I do the math then, but I have trouble

EDIT:

[image]

Example: I have an event that lasts just one day. So I give it the option 'allDay' => true.
We see on the picture on the day 'Sat 02/11' that it is directly set for the whole day. It's OK!

Now, if I have an event that should last 2.5 days. It would be necessary that on this sight, during two days, it is marked in the line 'all the day', but that in the last day, it is not in 'all the day' but that one put him well in the schedules . But if I set the option 'allDay' of the event to true, then it will appear in the box 'all day' for 3 days!
And if I take away the option 'allDay', then in the weekly view, it will fill a whole day, as seen in the picture in the day of 'dim 03/11'. And it's really not aesthetic

Comment: daygridMonth has no real concept of time or "slots". It will simply show each event the same size. You can make it display the full start/end time of each event in the text if you like, but that's about the most you can do. If you need a more detailed display, then please us the Timegrid or Timeline views.

Comment: I suspect you are never going to be able to do this reliably in the month view just by setting CSS widths - as you say, it doesn't take into account the real width of the calendar cells, which you cannot know in advance (and can change if the window resizes). And since the events are not actually within the HTML element which creates the day cell (instead they are overlaid on top) you can't set a % width or anything like that to have it constrained by the container. It's also difficult (although perhaps not impossible, by using dates) to work out which cell(s) an event will be laid on top of.

Comment: Really, the correct way to do this would be to fork the code of the dayGridMonth plugin (it's open-source after all) and create your own [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) based on that code, but with extra functionality to represent the timed events in the way you're wanting to. But it's a lot of work, both to develop it to begin with, and to maintain it to be compatible with updates to fullCalendar. Consider whether you really do need this feature before starting, or whether you can just use one of the other view types to convey this information.

Comment: actually, this problem of screen size will persist. I also think that there is no way to reliably display this kind of event on the monthly view. it's a shame that a plugin like FullCalendar did not think of that!

Comment: So I do not have the choice to display 3 full days for an event that is supposed to last 2.5 days. And so the detail would be on the weekly view I imagine? But I noticed that for an event of 1.5 days for example, on the weekly view, it is either the event appears as being "All day" on the two days, or it will take all the schedules of the day and half of each other on the next day. You see what I mean ?

Comment: And sorry for my bad english I'm french I use a translator

Comment: " it is either the event appears as being "All day" on the two days, or it will take all the schedules of the day and half of each other on the next day." ...why is that a problem? I'm not entirely sure what your point is.

Comment: Actually if you follow the custom view route as I mentioned then you probably can overcome the problem because you have access to more of the internal code and calculations of the calendar. But it is not such an easy task to create that view, even if you copy the current "month" code to begin with.

Comment: I am not involved in the fullCalendar project, but to be honest I can see why the "month" view does not use times. For half-days or something it's maybe not such a problem, but if you allow that then you must allow for all times of day...and then the calculations for different times will create tiny differences in the widths of the events, but without any markers to show the exact times. It would be a mess and actually not very informative. Better to have a neat, overview of the events, and then get more detail from the "grid" views.

Comment: I don't know if you have ever used the calendar in Microsoft Outlook? The way fullCalendar draws its month and week views are very similar to that, which is a very successful product. I think their approach is reasonable.

Comment: P.S. The grid views (or timeline views) don't have to be fixed to a week or a day, actually. You can [create a custom duration for them](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings) to show more or less days in each view. That might be useful to you in some way.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand what you mean. You do not have trouble finally ... Look at my 1st post, I updated it to explain the problem that I will have to face now

Comment: I see. What you're proposing (part of the event in the all-day section and then the last part in the time grid) would be even more confusing, I think. It would not be clear that these two bits of colour are actually the same event - they would not be joined together in the display. Anyway, what you're seeing is just the way the calendar works, there's not much you can do about it (except for custom views again). Outlook works in the same way in its "week" view. If you give an event a time (as well as a date) then it appears in the timed area so you can see exactly how much time it takes up.

Comment: For multi-day events I agree it can look a bit strange because it fills the whole area of the grid on the full days, but it's actually totally logical. Of course you can always use the calendar options to reduce the hours which are on display in the grid (e.g. if you don't need to show night-time hours). Or if the event really only take place 9am-5pm each day then you could use a recurring event instead of a single continuous event. That might make it look neater. it depends on your exact requirement, of course. But those are some ideas to think about.

Comment: Okay, you're probably right, it's better that way! I have one last question, but a little more level-oriented code. I intend to display a kind of form to the right of my calendar for the user to select options, to be able to filter events dynamically with Ajax. It's possible ? Should I create a new post?

Comment: yes it's certainly possible. But yes you should create a new post since that's a whole new issue. In it, please your current code to attempt the filtering and explain where you're stuck exactly.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will create the new post !